# How do my abilities level on the command board?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

In Birth By Sleep, at the end of each game on the Command Board Minigame, the abilities I've used gain experience. I've seen a number of places that say things to the effect of:

> Playing your abilities on the board will earn you experience.

And even so far as:

> You will draw cards not maxed out first. Always

And

> If your opponent buys your space, that command will not gain experience.

But what actions will actually give me experience? Do I just need to play my card? Do I need to level it (the tile on the board, I mean)? Will I earn more experience if my opponents land on it? What actual event(s) trigger my gaining of experience and what factors dictate how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leveling up your panel on the Command Board will increase the CP/EXP you get when the game ends. It is influenced by its value of the panel, or the price you paid for it (NOT what other players pay when they land on it). Press (Circle) on the panel to see the value. The placement of the panels matter as well.

**Example**

If you land on a Command Panel (not a Bonus Panel [no star]) that costs 300BP and set a LVL1 Command on it, the value of the panel will be 300BP, the cost to your opponents that land on the tile will be ~50BP.

If you level it up to LVL5 by paying 2000BP, now your panel with LVL1 Command is worth 2300BP, cost to land on the panel will be ~1000BP)

If you purchase two or more panels adjacent to each other with a
card of the same type (they will be the same color: magic cards, attack cards, crown cards, etc.), they will form a chain and increase each other's value by 10%.

When you finish the board game, that LV1 Command will receive CP/EXP **proportional** to its value (in other words, you won't won't get exactly 2300CP if the value of the panel is 2300BP). You will get a bonus to CP/EXP if you come in first place as well.

You can buy an opponent's panel by paying five times the value of the land. If you do, you will gain w/e commands are set to that panel.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the Minigame. At the end of the minigame, the abilities you used in the game gain experience, just like you were in battle. But my question is what is it that gains experience. The FAQ states "When you use a card to buy a panel, you will gain experience for that command." But I don't think that is all you gain experience for. And if it is, I'm looking for something a bit more focused on that. I'll clarify my question a bit to include this info

Comment: Oh I think I know what you are talking about. When you set a command to a (command) panel (you can use more than 1 card). The set command will gain experience when you when the game ends (only if you still but control it). How much experience you gain is determined by the value of the panel.

Comment: Is that all it is determined by? Or does an enemy landing on the panel add to the gained amount? And is it based on total value in BP, or just what level the panel is (1-5)?

Comment: Opponents landing on a panel you own will only transfer BP to you. The higher the level of the panel, the larger the value. This is all explained when you play first play the Keyblade Board. Go give it a try and see for yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I play it quite a lot to try and power level my abilities. But I'm trying to more sufficiently power level my abilities, so I'm trying to figure out what factors add to the amount of exp my abilities gain after so I can maximize those factors. So my question is, what events in the minigame actually translate to exp for my abilities in the real game. Does an opponent landing on it just give me BP in the minigame, or does it add to the exp I earn at the end?

Comment: The value of the panel is what ultimately determines how much CP/EXP you gain at the end of the game. I've updated my answer with a more detailed example. Let me know if it clears things up.

Comment: Perfect. The BP -> Exp relationship is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)